# Removing query string parameter from Google analytics pageview report

Tags: google-analytics

My website uses a querystring parameter to track where on the site a user came from to access the current page. For example:

```
http://example.com/my-page?source=header
http://example.com/my-page?source=footer
http://example.com/my-page?source=sidebar
```

As we all know, this causes Google Analytics to treat each of these urls as a separate page in reports. For example, the "All Pages" report.

Is there any way to create a custom report to display the same data as the "All Pages" report, but ignore the `source` querystring paramter, so that the three url's listed above would be grouped together as a single page?

I am aware that I can filter out query string parameters on the view level, but this is not what I'm looking to do. I don't want to ignore the parameters fully because I use them in other aspects of analysis. I just want the ability to ignore them on certain reports.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

No I don't believe you can tell GA to reprocess data like that for specific reports. One option is that you could create a new view where you have excluded the query parameters, so you can create as many reports as you need with it removed.

Answer (score 1):

The only functionality Google Analytics has for this is on the view level: "Exclude URL Query Parameters".   I can be found under **Admin** -> **View Settings**:

[image: Google Analytics Exclude URL Query Parameters]

[The documentation for it](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en) says:

> Any query parameters or unique session IDs (e.g., sessionid or vid) that appear in your URLs that you do not want to see in your reports. Enter as a comma-separated list.
>
> This setting is case sensitive. There is a 2048-character limit.
>
> Additionally, the parameters you identify here are excluded before filters are applied, so be sure you identify them here as they appear in the original, unfiltered URIs. It has become a common mistake to apply filters, and then return to these settings to identify query parameters as they appear in your filtered reports, thus ignoring the case-sensitive requirement of this setting.
>
> For example, if the original URI is `/Section1?ParameterA=something` and you use a filter to change it to `/section1?parametera=something` for your reports, then when you identify the query parameter here, you need to identify it as ParameterA

So in your case, you would just fill in `source` into that box.  If you had a second parameter to exclude you would add it in after a comma: `source,sessionid`.

---

Googlebot is also going to get confused about these tracking parameters and it could lead to SEO problems.   You can tell Googlebot about the parameter using the [Search Console URL Parameters Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en).

I'd recommend not using tracking parameters on your URLs because of the problems and confusion it causes.

Comment: My website contains a lot use of parameter `page`. So, the analytic is separated like `/section`, `/section?page=2`,`/section?page=3`. So, I have added `page` into exclude URL Query Parameters field. However, after I save and go back to analytic page, the result is still separated. Not combine into one. Do I need to wait for new data for it to combine into one?

Comment: Yes you need to wait.  Filters only effect data going forward.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the clean URL plugin, or custom code in Google Tag Manager

https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/plugins/clean-url-tracker.md

Comment: Can you explain more? Such as, how the plugin works or how to use it? Short link only answers are often flagged by the system as being low quality. Cheers!!