# How to filter a Google Analytics report by url query params?

Tags: google-analytics

I try to aggregate the several variations depending on query values of a page to one result, so `page.php`, `page.php?action=edit`, `page.php?action=history`, ... is about the same page. Using a filter (see screenshot) and applying it to my View doesn't work although I think the filter is okay. Filter verification says: *"This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small.""*

[image]

Comment: Do you need to be able to access the different URL parameters in any reports after these have been filtered? Or is it fine to lose them entirely? Filters should be able to handle parameters without a problem, but you might have better luck using the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" function, as per this answer: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/95865/54360

Comment: Thanks, but well, I'd rather keep the original urls, but more importantly: View-settings only take effect at the time of change and have no effect on the historical statistics.

Comment: The same is true of filters.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, are you sure?

Comment: Yes, view level filters do not change existing data, and they can take 24 hours to take effect.